# Noise signal passed thru Normal ( Gaussian Random variable) distribution system : exam problem?

Tags: signal, signal-theory

[image]

I know that Fx(x)= F((x+a)/o)

I don't know how to find Fx(x) that satisfy the p(y>=0)
can someone clear this point to me?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$P( y\ge 0)=P(x\ge -1)=\int_{-1}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx$$